# Accessing env vars when deploying React app to Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

**I have deployed my React app to Azure App Service following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIKfy4NptTE). I have chosen Linux and PHP 7.3 for the stack. I have set up a pipeline in Azure DevOps to automatically get my code from GitHub, create a production build and deploy to my Azure App Service.**

Everything works fine, *except* my React app does not appear to have access to any of my *environment variables*. Neither the ones defined in `.env` or `.env.production`, nor the ones configured through the Azure Application Settings.

This all works fine locally during development, i.e. when using the Webpack Dev Server that comes with create-react-app.

Is the problem the PHP stack I have chosen (I assume Webpack uses a Node server, hence allowing me to access the env vars locally)? If so, how can I address this? As I understand it, I need the PHP stack to be able to run the index.html in my React app's build folder?

I have tried changing my Azure App Service stack from PHP to Node, but in that case Azure won't run my React app and just shows me the default App Service ready page?

**Basically, what do I need to do to be able to have access to my env vars defined in `.env` or `.env.production` or configured through the Azure Application Settings?**

Comment: CRA by default doesn’t do server-side rendering. It can’t inject environment variables during content serving (like Next.js does). During transpiling, Webpack process replaces all occurrences of process.env with a string value that was given. This means it can only be configured during build time.
See: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/

Comment: Ok, but how would I replicate "During transpiling, Webpack process replaces all occurrences of process.env with a string value that was given" on Azure? PS: I don't want server-side rendering, just env vars.